# Merge keys array with values array and sum if same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, I have two separated arrays, they always have the same number of items and look like this:

```
array1 = ["Chicken","Chicken","Beef","Shrimp","Beef","Chicken"]
array2 = [2,3,4,1,3,2]
```

How can I sum values of all corresponding items like this:

```
Chicken: 7
Beef: 7
Shrimp: 1
```

Cheers

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this**

```js
let array1 =["Chicken","Chicken","Beef","Shrimp","Beef","Chicken"]
let array2 = [2,3,4,1,3,2]

let op = array1.reduce((output,current,index)=>{
    if(output[current]){
      output[current] +=array2[index];
    } else {
      output[current] = array2[index];
    }
    return output;
},{})

console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` and `.reduce()` methods to get the resultant object:

```js
let array1 = ["Chicken", "Chicken", "Beef", "Shrimp", "Beef", "Chicken"];
let array2 = [2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2];

let result = array1.map((v, i) => [v, array2[i]])
                   .reduce((r, [k, v]) => (r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + v, r), {});

console.log(result);
```

**References:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a **single** [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const keys = ["Chicken","Chicken","Beef","Shrimp","Beef","Chicken"]
const vals = [2,3,4,1,3,2]

console.log(keys.reduce((r,c,i) => 
   (r[keys[i]] = (r[keys[i]] || 0) + vals[i], r), {}))
```

or broken down and more readable format:

```js
const keys = ["Chicken","Chicken","Beef","Shrimp","Beef","Chicken"]
const vals = [2,3,4,1,3,2]

const result = keys.reduce((r,c,i) => {
  let key = keys[i]
  r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + vals[i]
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```